# Received too many arguments to function byFeature(). Expected at most 3 but got 4

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, ndvi, landsat, land-cover

I Used a boundary shapefile as geometry in Google Earth Engine, and got the error:

> Line 37: Received too many arguments to function byFeature(). Expected at most 3 but got 4

How can I solve this error?

Below is the code

```
// Define function to add NDVI band to Landsat 5 images.
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI'));
};

// Load Landsat 5 collection, filter to 1982, and select region of interest
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterDate('1982-01-01', '1982-12-31')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .map(addNDVI)
  .select('NDVI');

// Define function to calculate median NDVI by date and region.
var timeseries = collection.reduce(ee.Reducer.median())
  .reduceRegions({
    collection: geometry,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
    scale: 30
  });
  
  // Define properties to use for chart x-axis and chart series.
var chartXProperties = {
  sortAscending: true,
  title: 'Date',
  sortProperty: 'system:index'
};

var chartSeriesProperties = {
  title: 'Median NDVI',
  lineWidth: 1,
  pointSize: 3,
};

// Create and display chart.
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(timeseries, 'system:index', ['median'], chartXProperties)
  .setChartType('LineChart')
  .setOptions(chartSeriesProperties);

print(chart);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two main issues with your code:

- the timeseries object contains only one value. This is because you first use `ee.ImageCollection.reduce()` which gives you a single image, followed by `.reduceRegions`, which gives you a feature collection of only one value (assuming geometry is only one region). Therefore, there is no time series information.
- the `ui.Chart.feature.byFeature` expects three arguments, as mentioned in the documentation: `(features, xProperty, yProperties)`. As explained by the error in your question title, the function expects only 3 arguments, and you gave 4. Your `chartXProperties` can be given to the `ui.Chart` using `ui.Chart.setOptions`, just as you did for the `chartSeriesProperties`.

Here is a slightly modified version of your code, but fixing the above two issues:

```js
// Define function to add NDVI band to Landsat 5 images. 
var addNDVI = function(image) { return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI')); };

// Load Landsat 5 collection, filter to 1982, and select region of interest 
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
.filterDate('1984-01-01', '1985-08-31')
.filterBounds(geometry)
.map(addNDVI)
.select('NDVI');

// Define function to calculate median NDVI by date and region. 
var timeseries = collection
// //.reduce(ee.Reducer.median())   // this will give you just an image.. 
//.reduceRegions({ collection: geometry, reducer: ee.Reducer.median(), scale: 30 }); // so this will return only one value!

// Better to map it as below:
function get_median(image){
  // Get the median by using reduceRegion on one image:
  return image
  .reduceRegions({ collection: geometry, reducer: ee.Reducer.median(), scale: 30 })
  .map(function(f){
    return f.set({"date":image.date()})    // Keep the image's date as a property.
  }); 
}
var timeseries = ee.FeatureCollection(collection.map(get_median)).flatten().sort("date")
print(timeseries)
print(timeseries.aggregate_array("median")) // 19 values
print(timeseries.aggregate_array("date")) // 19 dates


// Define properties to use for chart x-axis and chart series. 
var chartXProperties = { sortAscending: true, title: 'Date', sortProperty: 'date' };
var chartSeriesProperties = { title: 'Median NDVI', lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 3, };

// Create and display chart. 
// ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(features, xProperty, yProperties)
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(timeseries, 'date', ['median'])
.setChartType('LineChart')
.setOptions(chartSeriesProperties)
.setOptions(chartXProperties)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/85dee16d52cb3394c80aaffd6ef5a32d